# Haskell - Tuples and Lists as built-in types: how are they actually declared?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, typing

In chapter 2 of "A gentle introduction to Haskell", user-defined types are explained and then the notion that built-in types are, apart from a special syntax, no more different than user-defined ones:

> Earlier we introduced several "built-in" types such as lists, tuples, integers, and characters. We have also shown how new user-defined types can be defined. Aside from special syntax, are the built-in types in any way more special than the user-defined ones? The answer is no. (The special syntax is for convenience and for consistency with historical convention, but has no semantic consequences.)

So you could define a tuple like to the following:

```
 data (a,b)              = (a,b)                         
 data (a,b,c)            = (a,b,c)
 data (a,b,c,d)          = (a,b,c,d)
```

Which sure you cannot because that would require an infinite number of declarations. So how are these types actually implemented? Especially regarding the fact that only against a type declaration you can pattern-match?

Comment: You are not going to use an infinite number of tuple arities in any given program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since GHC is open source, we can just look at it:

---

The tuples are a lot less magical than you think:

From https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC/Tuple.hs

```
data (a,b) = (a,b)
data (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)
data (a,b,c,d) = (a,b,c,d)
data (a,b,c,d,e) = (a,b,c,d,e)
data (a,b,c,d,e,f) = (a,b,c,d,e,f)
data (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
-- and so on...
```

So, tuples with different arities are just different data types, and tuples with very big number of arities is not supported.

---

Lists are also around there:

From  https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/ghc-prim/GHC/Types.hs#L101

```
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
```

But there is a little bit of magic (special syntax) for lists.

---

Note: I know that GitHub is not where GHC is developed, but searching "ghc source code" on Google did not yield the correct page, and GitHub was the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You defined *three* tuple types there, not *one* hence your argument with the infinite number of declarations doesn't cut. A standard confoming Haskell needs to support only a finite number of tuple types. Hence finitely many declarations.

In fact, you can define:

```
 data Pair a b = Pair a b
```

and this is isomorphic to an ordinary 2-tuple.